# SQL Logic issue and renaming of tables

Tags: sql-server, case

I have 2 problems here i want to check if there's any Record in my table Source_Patient that has the column IsProcessed evaluated to true in the case that Batch.SourceId = 1
, when Batch.SourceId = 2 i want to check the same but in the table Plain_Data ,If Plain_Data has any record with the column IsProcessed evaluated to true (Plain_Data.IsProcessed = 1). The other problem related with the query is how do i Rename the table inside the CASE?

This is what i have so far but it's not working, i get the error "Incorrect Syntax near the keyword 'FROM'" but i guess the error is pretty generic, the query is not well constructed, i also attached the data model :

## Query

```
SELECT 
    Batch.Id AS BatchId,
    Source.Id AS SourceId ,
    Source.Label AS SourceLabel,
    Batch.Number AS BNumber,
    RawData.Id AS RawDataId,
    (CASE 
        WHEN Batch.SourceId = 1 THEN 
            (CASE 
               WHEN 1=(SELECT TOP 1 FROM Source_Patient.IsProcessed = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0
    CASE        
        WHEN Batch.SourceId = 2 THEN 
            (CASE 
                WHEN 1=(SELECT TOP 1 FROM Plain_Data.IsProcessed = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0
    ) AS IsProcessed
   
    FROM Batch
LEFT JOIN RawData ON Batch.Id = RawData.BatchId
LEFT JOIN Plain_Data ON RawData.Id = Plain_Data.RawDataId
INNER JOIN Source_Patient ON Source_Patient.BatchId=Batch.Id
INNER JOIN Source ON Batch.SourceId = Source.Id
```

## DataModel

```
Batch

Id
SourceId (FK) - table Source
Number
Code
StartedAt
EndedAt


RawData

id
SourceId (FK) - table Source
BatchId (FK) - table Batch
CreatedAt

Source_Patient

Id
BatchId (FK) - table Batch
PatientId
NameFirst
NameLast
IsProcessed (Boolean)

Plain_Data

Id
RawDataId (FK) - table RawData
FirstName
LastName
IsProcessed (Boolean)

Source

Id
Label
```

Comment: "not working" doesn't mean anything. Please explain what the issue is.

Comment: Incorrect Syntax near the keyword 'FROM'. But i believe the error is pretty generic i think the query is not correct on itself i guess

Comment: Can you move that nested case statement earlier in the select list and see if you get the same error? Then edit your question and add the error.

Comment: This certainly makes no sense: `SELECT TOP 1 FROM Source_Patient.IsProcessed = 1`. I guess the issue in in that nested case somewhere. Try removing it and see if the error goes away. This is debugging 101

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.        so...3 times the same error now

Comment: You need to select a column after `Top 1`. `SELECT TOP 1 <column_name> FROM Source_Patient.IsProcessed = 1`. That's the reason for the error.

Comment: tried with this and the error remains the same: CASE 
               WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0

Comment: I see that you are in the habit of asking questions and never marking any answer as 'correct'. Please review some of your old questions and mark as correct where applicable.

Comment: CASE statements need an END at the end e.g., `CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Comment: im sorry but most of those replies are comments like this here , where can i upvote  for example you comment above? i only see a flag

Comment: tried this, still the same error (CASE 
        WHEN Batch.SourceId = 1 THEN 
            (CASE 
               (CASE WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)            
        WHEN Batch.SourceId = 2 THEN 
                (CASE WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    END) AS IsProcessed

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of issues with your syntax... try this and see if this works for you. The only issue I'm having here is that you need to correlate the subquery with the current record ID. But I hope this points you in the right direction.

```
SELECT 
    B.Id AS BatchId,
    S.Id AS SourceId ,
    S.Label AS SourceLabel,
    B.Number AS BNumber,
    RD.Id AS RawDataId,
    (CASE 
        WHEN B.SourceId = 1 THEN 
            (SELECT TOP 1 Case When ISNULL(SP1.IsProcessed,0) = 1 Then 1 Else 0 END FROM Source_Patient SP1 Where SP1.IsProcessed = 1 AND SP1.BatchID = SP.BatchID) 
            
        WHEN B.SourceId = 2 THEN 
            (SELECT TOP 1 Case When ISNULL(PD1.IsProcessed,0) = 1 Then 1 Else 0 END FROM Plain_Data PD1 Where PD1.IsProcessed = 1 AND PD1.RawDataID = ISNull(PD.RawDataID,0)) ELSE 0 END
    ) AS IsProcessed
   
    FROM Batch B
LEFT JOIN RawData RD ON B.Id = RD.BatchId
LEFT JOIN Plain_Data PD ON RD.Id = PD.RawDataId
INNER JOIN Source_Patient SP ON SP.BatchId=B.Id
INNER JOIN Source S ON B.SourceId = S.Id
```

Comment: what do you mean with correlate with the current record ID?  so your query is something like if Batch.DataSource=1 then it will evaluate to true if this (SELECT TOP 1 IsProcessed FROM Source_Patient Where IsProcessed = 1) returns a value? WHat will happen in your else? i don't understand the first ELSE. Basically i am not sure if checking (SELECT TOP 1 IsProcessed FROM Source_Patient Where IsProcessed = 1) is false it will evaluate the next WHEN Batch.SourceId=2....

Comment: The error that i am getting is "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHEN'. Incorrect Syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.

Comment: I'm trying to use the Select statement to get the value of the bit, either 1 or 0. See if the update works.

Comment: well due to my datamodel im wondering if (SELECT TOP 1 IsProcessed FROM Plain_Data Where IsProcessed = 1)  my query recognizes the Plain_Data table with this here LEFT JOIN Plain_Data ON RawData.Id = Plain_Data.RawDataId

Comment: To answer your question... You are selecting Top 1 where IsProcessed = 1 for the whole table. Is that what you want? or do you want it to select based on the BatchID or RawDataID?

Comment: No... the subquery is totally separate as I explained above.

Comment: You may want to alias all of your tables for clearer understanding, especially using subqueries.

Comment: I've updated the answer with alias' and also the subquery join to the outer tables as I think it should be... Hope this works.

Comment: at least no errors now! just 1 question why are you not using else after this statement  (SELECT TOP 1 IsNull(IsProcessed,0) FROM Source_Patient SP1 Where IsProcessed = 1 AND SP1.BatchID = SP.BatchID)

Comment: oh ok i got it thanks! I marked your answear as correct. But for example here i am doing first of all a left join and then i am using a data Set that can be null   " FROM Batch B
LEFT JOIN RawData RD ON B.Id = RD.BatchId
LEFT JOIN Plain_Data PD ON RD.Id = PD.RawDataId " there's a lot of issues here right?

Comment: well it actually doesn't give me an error but, i receive every single row as true when there are values that evaluate to false...@SS_DBA

Comment: Interesting... let me change the subqueries to see if we can get the correct answer.

Comment: Give that a shot and see... could have been the NULL ID from the RawData table.